# Window resize area, Firefox automaximizes and Giant Ubuntu Bar

Tags: 12.04, updates, system-settings, system-tray

everybody

Yesterday (Feb 07, 2014) I updated  my Ubuntu 12.04 and now I'm feeling I'm going postal!

- The ubuntu bar changed its size for the comfortable 24px I had set to 20457px or something equally ridiculous. The systems now only allows it to set it to 32px.
- Whenever I change desktops, my firefox windows get maximized.
- The area to resize windows changed for my comfortable 6px to the usual sociophatic 1/4px with which ubuntu usually punishes its users.

So my questions are:

- How do I undo those crappy "improvements"?
- Why ubuntu hates its users?

Sorry for the rant. My questions are sincere. I want my old configuration back and I'm pissed for this "I know better than you" attitude of this last upgrade.

Comment: try Tweak tool :https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the cause was that after the upgrade, the system stop recognizing the video card, and the system began to use unity-2d.

Unfortunately, the easiest way to fix it was to install ubuntu 13.10.